# Send SMS to a mobile port

Tags: php, sms

I want to know the PHP coding for sending the messages to the mobile port.

Answer (score 2):

Try searching first?
[SMS from web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432944/sms-from-web-application)

Answer (score 2):

To send sms from the php to the mobile you need to use any mobile solution provider like clickatell.com

They provides all the api details and sample code though which you can send sms.