# How to send text messages to site users

Tags: php, mysql, sms

I have a site that I would like to send all of the users (20-100) text messages about 2 or 3 times a year.  What are my options? and how do I implement this into a php/mysql based site?

Any and all suggestions are welcome.  Feel free to let me know if I need to provide more information for clarity.

Comment: What contact info do you have?

Comment: Dupe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/432944/sms-from-web-application

Comment: When you talk of "text messages", do you think of SMS or "short text-based messages independent of the ways of medium"?

Comment: minimal: cell phone number and name only

Comment: Mike B: No dupe, at least not on purpose.

Martin H: I am simply imagining a user gets something sent to their phone when I desire.

Comment: @ServAce85 how does your question differ from the one I referenced? It might help us understand your end-goal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might try something like [this](http://www.sephiroth.it/tutorials/flashPHP/sms/).

Answer (score 0):

You have to buy an SMS gateway API from the vendor and implement with that 
www.SMSCountry.com is a good option