# How to convert this wget function to php?

Tags: php, xml, linux, wget

```
wget -d --header="Content-Type:application/xml" --post-data="$(cat <your xml file>)" http://sample.sample.com/api
```

How do i use this function in php?
I want also to get the response from this function.
i have a variable in php the viable is like this

```
$xml = '<sample>
    <Request target="test">
    </Request>
</sample>'
```

This is the xml that i want to post.

I tried the following:

```
$url = 'sample.sample.com/api';;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "$(cat <".$xml.">)"); // receive server response ...
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
echo $server_output = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
```

But it returned this error:

> Parsing XML failed: Start tag expected, '<' not found

Comment: Have you tried php curl object ?

Comment: i dont know how to use curl to function like this wget function ... if you know how to make curl work like this it will be great

Comment: Duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3080146/post-data-to-url-php

Comment: Read http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Comment: There are basic curls examples in the documentation. Read them, try them, and if you run into problems, ask about them here. http://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php

Comment: no its not the same i did exaclty like this fucntion i get this response from the server  Parsing XML failed: Start tag expected, '<' not found

Comment: Then show us what you have tried and we will help.

Comment: $url = 'http://sample.sample.com/api';
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
            "$(cat <".$xml.">)");

// receive server response ...
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

echo $server_output = curl_exec ($ch);

curl_close ($ch);

Comment: @Aviv, please post the code as an edit to your original question. That way it's formatted for easy viewing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to follow a similar scenario as shown at [Sending and Receiving XML using PHP](http://www.bharath.co.uk/articles/2011/05/php-sending-and-receiving-xml-using-php). The second portion of that site (To send XML) uses curl to handle this operation which has similar properties to wget, but utilizing the PHP library rather than a command line binary and parameters. I'll include this snippet from the site for longevity.

```
<?php
  /*
   * XML Sender/Client.
   */
  // Get our XML. You can declare it here or even load a file.
  $xml_builder = '
                  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
                  <Test>
                      <String>I like Bharath.co.uk!</String>
                  </Test>
                 ';
  // We send XML via CURL using POST with a http header of text/xml.
  $ch = curl_init('http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/xml'));
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml_builder);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://www.bharath..co.uk');
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  $ch_result = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  // Print CURL result.
  echo $ch_result;
?>
```

Comment: if i use this curl_init('http://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); and run the script it just never finishes loading, but if i change it to $ch = curl_init(); it runs but i get nothing in response

Comment: With curl_init, it will set CURLOPT_URL to the value passed to the function. So for you try, http://sample.sample.com/api

Answer (score 0):

I think so ...

```
$cmd = "wget -d --header=\"Content-Type:application/xml\" --post-data=\"$(cat <your xml file>)\" http://sample.sample.com/api";
exec($cmd);
$outputfile = "dl.html";
echo file_get_contents($outputfile);
```

Comment: There are more system-efficient ways to do this than shelling out. Curl is the right tool.