# Receive postback and foward/send/hit to other postback

Tags: javascript, php, postback

Im still new in php. 
Is that possible to forward/send all parameter from incoming postback to another postback url?

Example, i receive postback url from A http://www.a.com?subid=name&country=malaysia&price=usd50.
Then i would like to forward/sent parameter from postback url A to postback url B http://www.b.com?subid=name&country=malaysia&price=usd50

I know how to get parameter from postback A and update the database. But in this case, i dont want to update database, i just want it forward or send all parameter value received from A to postback B.

Comment: Yes you can.  Just capture the data and send it to the new URL.

Comment: @JeremyMiller you mean use redirect to new url?

Comment: The urls you posted show GET data, not POST data fyi

Comment: Depends on the method you're using to post, but if you are POST'ing, then you can't just redirect -- you'd have to use a form and submit it using JS.

Comment: @Huey yes. i get data from url A and want to hit url B with data received from url A

Comment: Yes, I understand what you mean, but I'm just pointing out there is [a difference between GET & POST data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477333/what-is-the-difference-between-post-and-get).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's definitely possible.

```
//First, grab the POST data
$sub_id = $_GET['subid'];
$country = $_GET['country'];
$price = $_GET['price'];
```

Next, use curl as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3080146/post-data-to-url-php)

```
$url = 'http://www.someurl.com';
$myvars = 'subid=' . $sub_id. '&country=' . $country . '&price=' . $price;

$ch = curl_init( $url );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $myvars);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$response = curl_exec( $ch );
```

Comment: Hi. correction. $_POST will not get data from A. I use $_GET to get data.

Comment: Great that you sorted that out! But there's very little change to the php code, just replace all the `$_POST` with `$_GET`

Comment: Yah i did it. Everything is work great right now. Thank you so much for help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
   $pass =substr($_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"],strlen(strtok($_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"],"?")));
    header("Location: http://www.b.com".$pass);
      exit();
```