# How to make a request of Google Geolocation API?

Tags: php, google-geolocation

I was thinking that using google geolocation request is the same as using google distance matrix, but I'm wrong.

So, I don't understand how it works. I tried putting this url in the address bar

```
https://www.googleapis.com/geolocation/v1/geolocate?key=MyAPIKey
```

I got nothing but `Not found` response. I'm expecting a response like:

```
{  
   "location": {
      "lat": 51.0,
      "lng": -0.1
   },
   "accuracy": 1200.4
}
```

Then I read there are some request body information in json that also have to be sent in the request but I don't know how to include them into the request. I want to do it with php. Please any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are calling it as a GET request, the api specifically states it must be made as a POST request. You will then get the JSON you expect to see.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by use native php **http stream** or with **curl**, here's an article explaining both methods [POST data to a URL in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3080146/post-data-to-a-url-in-php)
.

In your case there's no need for the `$data` or `curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $myvars);` lines as you don't need to send any parameters.