# How to call http post with parameters value in php

Tags: php, vb.net, http, post

I have code in VB.net code where we are entering a php url

```
IEPostStringRequest "www.example.com/call.php?" & Str1,

Sub IEPostStringRequest(URL, FormData)
    On Error Resume Next
  'Create InternetExplorer
 Set WebBrowser = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
  'You can uncoment Next line To see form results As HTML
  WebBrowser.Visible = False

  'Send the form data To URL As POST request
  Dim bFormData() As Byte
  ReDim bFormData(Len(FormData) - 1)
  bFormData = StrConv(FormData, vbFromUnicode)
  WebBrowser.Navigate URL, "_Self", , bFormData, _
    "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" + Chr(10) + Chr(13)

  Do While WebBrowser.busy
'    Sleep 100
    DoEvents
  Loop

  WebBrowser.Quit
End Sub
```

Now i want to fetch these parameters value in this www.example.com/call.php page.
when i am tried this $_POST['str']; but getting nothing.

Kindly help me.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$_GET['str']`.

For this to work, make sure your variable starts with 'str='. Otherwise, just do a `print_r($_GET)` in your php and get the names from that

If you are concatenating a string to the URL, you are not sending it as POST data, but rather as GET data.

To be able to send them as POST fields, you could use `curl`, if strictly necessary. For that, try to adapt this to VB: [POST data to a URL in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3080146/post-data-to-url-php)

Comment: $_GET , $_REQUEST already use it but still getting nothing and Array()

Comment: Can you post an example of `Str1`? I believe you are not assigning the value to a parameter name like call.php?str=Str1 (in the case Str1 does not start with 'str=')

Answer (score 0):

using get method ($_GET['str']) the data passing will be vulnerable.

it is better to send data via POST method.

example:

---------------------------------VB.NET PART-------------------------------

```
 Dim request As HttpWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create("http://xxx/xxx/test.php")
 request.Method = "POST"
 request.Proxy = Nothing

 Dim bytedata As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("name=Piyush")
 request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
 request.ContentLength = bytedata.Length

 Dim dataStream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
 dataStream.Write(bytedata, 0, bytedata.Length)
 dataStream.Close()
```

---------------------------------PHP PART-------------------------------

```
$name= isset($_POST["name"]) ? ($_POST["name"]):"";
echo $name;
```

this will pass parameter to PHP file.