# Returning a value from a php page inside an html value tag

Tags: php, html

I want to create an html page that converts fahrenheint degrees to celsius.
The html page is there for input and displaying the result and the php page makes the actual calculation.

I have to insert the value returned by the php page inside the label Celsius.
This means that I have to send data to the php page and the result must be displayed inside the label that can't be modified.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Convert</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="convert.php" method="POST">
        <label for="f">Fahrenheit</label>
        <input type="text" name="fahrenheit" id="f" />
        <br>
        <br>
        <label for="c">Celsius</label>
        <input type="text" name="celsius" readonly="read" id="c" value= "<?php echo $celsius;?>" />
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" name="conf" value="Confirm" />
        <input type="reset" value="Reset" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

---

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if (isset($_POST['fahrenheit']) && is_numeric($_POST['fahrenheit'])) {
        $fahrenheit = $_POST['fahrenheit'];
        $celsius = ($fahrenheit - 32) * 5 / 9;
        $_POST['celsius'] = (string) $celsius;
        echo $_POST['celsius'];
    } else {
        echo "Only numbers";
    }
    header('Location: eyo.html');
    return;
?>
```

Comment: Your PHP code should not call `echo` before calling `header()`. The headers MUST be sent before all other data.

Comment: Also you need to wrap your php statements with php tags. This `value=echo "$celsius;"` should be `value="<?php echo $celsius;?>"`

Comment: These pages should probably both be PHP, not HTML and PHP. A straight HTML page will have no particular way of retrieving data from PHP unless you plan to use AJAX.

Comment: @bytesized alright,fixed the header position and how would it work using AJAX?Pretty new to it

Comment: @ChadFisher yup,forgot to update that,thanks for reminding

Comment: `value=echo "$celsius;"` it doesn't quite work that way and it's unsure if your entire code is inside the same file or not.

Comment: @ManuelSgro Do the pages have to be separate?

Comment: @ChadFisher Yup,would've made things much easier putting everything in one page

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/42305297/4 you went and edited that to `value= "<?php echo $celsius;?>"` from the original `value=echo "$celsius;"` where an answer posted "before" that stealth edit showed you what you did wrong. In any case; see the answers below and accept the one you think is the best answer. "Stealth" btw means "changing your code without marking it as an additional edit" or informing others that you did a mistake or borrowed the code from (a) given answer(s).

Comment: @Fred-ii- I make amends still learning how the conventions work here :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have to do it in 2 pages, I would consider an approach like this:

Form Page (form-page.php):

```
<?php
$celsius = isset($celsius) ? $celsius : null;
?>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Convert</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="convert.php" method="POST">
    <label for="f">Fahrenheit</label>
    <input type="text" name="fahrenheit" id="f" />
    <br>
    <br>
    <label for="c">Celsius</label>
    <input type="text" name="celsius" readonly="read" id="c" value= "<?php echo $celsius;?>" />
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="conf" value="Confirm" />
    <input type="reset" value="Reset" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Convert Page (convert.php):

```
<?php

$celsius = null;

if(isset($_POST['fahrenheit']) )
{
    if (is_numeric($_POST['fahrenheit']))
    {
        $fahrenheit         = $_POST['fahrenheit'];
        $celsius            = ($fahrenheit-32)*5/9;
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Only Numbers Please!";
    }
}

include('form-page.php');

?>
```

Essentially we are posting data to the convert page, and including the form again after it.  The form page checks for the definition of the $celcius variable.

As the other comments mention I believe using AJAX or simply posting back to the same page is a much more effective solution to this problem, but alas we must use 2 pages o.O.

Comment: Yup,exactly what I wanted,Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Do everything in one page, here is what I did:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['fahrenheit']) && is_numeric($_POST['fahrenheit']))
   {
$fahrenheit=$_POST['fahrenheit'];
$celsius=($fahrenheit-32)*5/9;
   }
else 
    {
    echo "Only numbers"; 
    } 
?>
```

Thats my PHP section, paste it at the top of the page. Obviously set the Method in your HTML to the page name. Then echo out the variable to the celcius input. You do not have it correct currently on here:

```
<input type="text" name="celsius" readonly="read" id="c" value=echo "$celsius;" />
```

This is in HTML not PHP. You need the PHP tags like so:

```
<input type="text" name="celsius" readonly="read" id="c" value="<?php echo $celsius; ?>" />
```

If you change your form method to the current page, implement the code I have posted above the HTML form, and so long as your web host disables on screen errors, this will work just fine. Tweak as needed of course to suit your needs, but this is how I would at least get started for posting the celcius conversion.

Comment: Also make sure to make your page .php and not .html to process everything on one page, this is what I have exactly: http://pasteboard.co/zwTtVIzhB.png

Comment: Unfortunately I gotta do it in separate pages,if everything fails I'll resort to your solution :)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to write some code to perform the opposite operation, you'll need to write a POST operation that will send the result of the celcius calculation to your same "convert.php" page where you will need to handle this new request call.

See the following link on how to perform a post in PHP:
[POST data to a URL in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3080146/post-data-to-a-url-in-php)

Then in your "convert.php" you modify your code that receives the parameters like this:

```
if (isset($_POST['celsius']) && is_numeric($_POST['celsius'])) {
    $celsius = $_POST['celsius'];
}
```

And your HTML code should be something like:

```
<input type="text" name="celsius" readonly="read" id="c" value="<?php echo $celsius ?>" />
```

Comment: Sorry not sure if I follow,could make an example if you have time?