# MediaWiki 1.28: passing login parameters via POST method

Tags: php, mediawiki

I want to login to my website with a username and password, and be able to login to mediawiki app with the same credentials automatically.
Since Mediawiki 1.27 the username and password cannot be sent in the query string, it has to be done through POST method. I don't have PHP background and my application is in .NET.
How do I pass the credentials from my app to the mediawiki?
Current MW version im using is 1.28
PHP is 7.

Comment: You are searching for a Single Sign On (SSO) solution. This way the question is much too broad. Please research for a fitting SSO solution and try using it. Of course you can return to SO with difficulties in a specific tool.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Markus! I'm trying to establish this without using a SSO. According to the Mediawiki 1.28 release notes, passing parameters through the query string is deprecated and was suggested to make use of POST method instead.
I'm having a hard time figuring out how to send the credentials from my site to the POST method in MediaWiki.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [POST data to a URL in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3080146/post-data-to-a-url-in-php)