# How to send sms via php?

Tags: php, sms, sms-gateway

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SMS from web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432944/sms-from-web-application)

Sample code to send Mail via php

```
// In case any of our lines are larger than 70 characters, we should use wordwrap()
$message = wordwrap($message, 70);

// Send
mail('caffeinated@example.com', 'My Subject', $message);
?>
```

Is there any codes to send sms via php code. If there is no option i php. What would be the solution to send sms freely through php. How can i do this. Particularly within in india.

Comment: possible duplicate of [SMS from web application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/432944/sms-from-web-application), and [lots](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php+send+sms)

Comment: @ajreal my question is not a duplicate. i am asking for optional sms code in php as mail()

Comment: IC, mind to re-update your question with precise information ?

Comment: I don't see anything in your question that doesn't justify closing it for the given question or the many other questions dealing with sending sms via PHP. Please go through the linked questions and then update your own to point out why none of these solve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PLease refer these links

**http://www.sephiroth.it/tutorials/flashPHP/sms/**

http://www.ozekisms.com/index.php?owpn=327

http://www.theukwebdesigncompany.com/articles/article.php?article=1583

http://www.nowsms.com/discus/messages/1/1113.html

Comment: you cannot add links to answer without necessary text, These links can die in future

Answer (score 1):

There are few free options. Your best bet would be to subscribe to an SMS service which allows you to send emails in the form of `012345678@smsprovider.net` where `012345678` is the telephone number which you want to send the sms to.

Answer (score 0):

[Most] phone numbers have email addresses.

Look about halfway down the page here:

http://www.email-unlimited.com/stuff/send-email-to-phone.htm

Hope that helps!

Comment: Not all carriers have email addresses to send SMS's to phone numbers with, it depends upon your/their carrier.

Comment: yeah, thanks for clearing that up.