# How to send mobile messages using php

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SMS from web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432944/sms-from-web-application)

I am in need to know how to send messages from a php website or any service provider api's are there to send the message. Is there any tutorial to follow or any step by step procedure.

Thanks,
Lokesh

Answer (score 0):

I use a service in Australia called SMSBullet.  Using their API it's as simple as requesting a URL. e.g.

```
<?php

$message = "This is your message";
$mobileNumber = "MOBILE-NUMBER-TO-SEND-TO";

$url = "https://www.smsbullet.com.au/msg.php?u=USERNAME&p=PASSWORD&d=".$mobileNumber."&rr=1&m=".urlencode($message);

$response = file_get_contents($url);

?>
```

In this example, the GET request is executed very simply using file_get_contents, you could also use CURL or fopen.

The parameters, response format etc will vary depending on which service provider you use.

Comment: According to - http://www.smsbullet.com.au/cover.php they do send to India mobile numbers. Though if that is your location, I would try to find a local provider with a similar service.

Comment: @Lokesh: Did you managed to solve the problem like this?