# How to send SMS through my website

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SMS from web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432944/sms-from-web-application)

Can any one suggest me how to send SMS through my website, which is a good one

Comment: +1 because possible duplicate doesn't mean that there is no research effort

Answer (score 0):

You can integrate some SMS services like CellTrust in your website and you will be able to send SMS.  I did the smiler task like that....

```
public function smsSend($number,$temppwd)
{
            $curl = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL,"https://gateway.celltrust.net/TxTNotify/TxTNotify?");
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "Username=xxxxx&Password=xxxx&CustomerNickname=xxxxxx&PhoneDestination=".$number."&%20CarrierId%20=5&Message=Hello, Your verification code is: ".$temppwd.". Thank you&XMLResponse=true");
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE); 
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
            $head=curl_exec ($curl);
            $httpCode = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
}
```